# PowerBI/Powershell - Get list of datasources that a PBIX file uses

Tags: powershell, powerbi, powerbi-desktop, azure-powershell, powershell-5.0

I am trying to get a list of datasources that a Powerbi file is using. I seen solutions online where I can use the ReportingService module to get a list but this only works when the PowerBI report is published online. Is there a solution that would work for a local file?

Here is the situation.
A user gives me a Powerbi file. In order for me to get a list of datasources, I have to go in manually and to take a look at sources manually. Ideally, I would like to use Powershell to get this list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't an API that can access the desktop application.  You would have to brute force it.

The PBX file is basically a Zip file which then contains separate files with JSON information.  You would have to follow the following steps:

1. Use Expand-Archive to get the files out of the PBX (Not sure if you will need to change the file extension first).
2. Read the "Connections" file (Which is Json).  It will have the various connection strings used by the model.

You can do this manually by changing the file extension to Zip and opening the Zip file directly, and looking at the connections file in notepad.

Comment: I did that before and looked at the connection file. It does not contain anything helpful. It just has the datasetid and reportid.

`{"Version":3,"RemoteArtifacts":[{"DatasetId":"{{ID}}","ReportId":"{{ID}}"}]}`

Comment: Which means your reports data source is a shared dataset, or it was downloaded without the dataset as part of the PBX.  You can call PowerBI APIs to get the details of the dataset connection information.

Comment: Alrighty, I was able to use the MicrosoftPowerBIMgmt.Data and the command Get-PowerBIDatasource to get the list of datasources. However, it's not returning the connection string or name. `Name              :
ConnectionString  :`

Comment: For the connection string you have to query the datasources

Comment: Can you post some sample code demonstrating that or point me to some documentation? Thanks a lot!

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/datasets/get-datasources.  Try the API instead of the commandlet.

Comment: I got it with what you gave me. Thanks!